Estimation of the the maximum relative error
This page is from the book
Baxandall, Liebeck - Vector Calculus
https://www.amazon.com/Vector-Calculus-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486466205
It's page 133, after the chapter 3.5 "Error estimation".
I have some troubles with Exercise 3 even though I was able to prove the statement from the hint.
But all I can say based on that is that $\rho(r) \approx 0.5%$
I think I am not sure how to interpret the problem even, what does it mean "estimate the maximum relative error". Based on exercise 2, we're just defined "relative error" $\rho(x) $(based on the error $\Delta{x}$) and we've somewhat defined how to compute it approximately for product and fraction of two variables $x,y$ (if we know already the relative errors for the two variables $x,y$).
I think the problem is simple, I am just not quite clear on the concept itself probably (the relative error concept).
EDIT:
Maybe the right way to interpret this problem is as follows: It's given that the relative error $\rho(l)$ ranges from $-0.2$% to $0.2$%, the relative error $\rho(V)$ ranges from $-0.3$% to $0.3$%. OK, if so, then of course the relative error $2 \rho(r)$ ranges from $-0.5$% to $0.5$% (because of that relation from the hint), and then we get the desired result for $\rho(r)$. Is that what is meant here?


Your approach under Edit is correct.  It is good to remember, as you did, that the error can be negative.  When you see $\rho(V)-\rho(l)$ it can get as large as $\pm 0.5\%$
